# Transition to Xcode 5 Mishaps and missing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, xcode4.6

I was using Xcode 4.6.1 and have already created an iphone/ipad application that was approved by apple and on the App Store. It was built for a minimum deployment target as 5.1 
Now it's time to make it compatible with the Arm 64 architecture and IOS7. So when i downloaded Xcode 5 and opened my application, i changed the document versioning to 6.1 once and then to 7.0 along with the project deployment target to 6.1 and 7.0. In both cases, and while running from Xcode 5 to an IOS 7 device, i noticed that my UISearchBar disappears, and the data inside my UITAbleView are not showing. It's certain that modifications should take place to make the app IOS 7 compatible…but what to do if nothing is showing ! is there anything obvious and i'm not seeing it ? any pointers ? 
 Keeping in mind, if i run the appellation from my Xcode 4.6.1 into an IOS 7 , it runs perfectly , but i have to use Xcode 5 now to support Arm 64 devices such as iPad air.
**UPDATE 1:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.77 green:0.77 blue:0.777 alpha:0.99];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.77 green:0.77 blue:0.777 alpha:0.99];

  //  for(int i = 0 ; i<=20 ; i ++){
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.317 green:0.317 blue:0.317 alpha:1];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
   // NSLog(@"this is the indexPath.row %ld" , (long)indexPath.row);
    int rowCount = indexPath.row;

    Author *author = [self.theauthorsLoadedFinal2 objectAtIndex:rowCount];


    if(isFiltered){
        author = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        

    }
    else{
        author = [theauthorsLoadedFinal2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       
    }
       cell.textLabel.text = author.name;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;


    return cell;

}
```

Please keep in mind that application is working with no bugs at all

Comment: Relevant code, please?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Also adding a screenshot of your app's screen in working and non-working conditions would help.

Comment: no no error messages at all, nothing is wrong ! just the data is not showing at all, now i found why the search bar was not showing it was an auto layout problem, but why no data is showing in the tableview

Comment: Screenshots, please. Also, all of your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation.

Comment: thank you @duci9y but i figured it out thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
 Xcode 5 has a different reference point then the old Xcode versions, which means , a value 24 for example as an 'X' position, is calculated differently in Xcode 5, so it wasn't any coding mishaps, it was just a positioning bug. Thank you for your time